# Word / Office 365 Mail Merge - Alternative to UDL file for SQL connection string

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, odbc, office365, mailmerge

We provide a large software suite, which amongst its functionality includes the ability to perform Mail Merges in MS Word / Office 365.

In order for Word to know where to get the merge field list and data from, we set up a .UDL file:-

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
Data Source=SQLInstanceInPlainText\SQLServerInPlainText;
Initial Catalog=DatabaseCatalogInPlainText;
User ID=UsernameInPlainText;
Password=PasswordInPLainText;
Persist Security Info=True;
```

As indicated, all the information in a .UDL file is ***stored in plain text***, including Username and Password (because Microsoft and security are two mutually exclusive concepts).

Up to now, this hasn't been a major issue: all of our clients have our software and their databases installed on a server physically located on their premises, and not externally accessible.

So, there was a security hole, but given someone would have to be physically in the building to take advantage of it, it was trivial.

However, we now have several companies (and more to come, no doubt) wanting to move over to a cloud-based system. We have duly modified our software to work entirely over Azure too, and are in the process of testing it.

And during the testing, we've come to the point where we need to update the .UDL file to point to the SQL Azure database.

This database is of course not physically located in their premises, it's in the cloud, and as such can be accessed from anywhere. In the case of at least one company, they want it accessible from people working at home / on site etc, and currently don't have any form of VPN set up to allow us to lock down which IP addresses can access it (we are trying to talk them into that!).

So, if we use a .UDL file, we are potentially putting this (and undoubtedly others) company in the situation someone can leak the database connection details and that's it, game over.

So, I'm looking for an alternative to a .UDL file, somehow, that will allow us to still use MS Word / Office 365 to perform mail merges.

Something that has encrypted details would at least be an improvement, but ***an ideal solution for us*** would be for MS Word / Office 365 to request the details from an .EXE program.

None of the rest of our software has hard-coded connection strings (e.g. in app.config), they're all stored heavily encrypted on our server. When the software starts, it requests the encrypted connection details for the selected database (most companies have several, e.g. a Live, a Test and a UAT, and their version of the software can only see their databases) from our server.

If it was possible for MS Word / Office 365 (perhaps via an Add-In, I've written Outlook Add-Ins so could give it a go) to request the connection details from a program instead of a .UDL file, we could apply the same solution and require the User to select the database and log in (with their software Username and Password, NOT the SQL Username and Password).

So, not only does no-one know the SQL connection details, any User that leaves has their software Username and Password revoked, so even if they still have the software (for example on a laptop) they can no longer access the system.

Likewise, if that laptop is lost or stolen, the person that ends up with it still can't get the details, because they won't have a login to our software.

Assuming, of course, that it's somehow possible to get MS Word / Office 365 to get the connection details from anything other than a file containing them in plain text...

TL;DR...

MS Word / Office 365 uses a .UDL file for SQL connection details for Mail Merges.

These details are stored in plain text, and so are a nasty security hole.

Locking down the database to specific IPs is not currently an option (clients, not us!)

We're looking for an alternative to .UDL files, ideally MS Word / Office 365 requesting the details from a .EXE program, but at a minimum something that stores the details in an encrypted form.

EDIT:

I mentioned a Word Add-In, if Word can use one of those to request the connection details directly (not through a separate .EXE program) then that would also be a great solution. The Outlook Add-In I wrote already does this, so I could probably pinch most of the code if someone could point me in the correct direction.

**Edit**: Attempt at Encrypting Connection String for ODC files

I found the following code, which encrypts connection strings for web.config and app.config

```
// Protect the connectionStrings section.
private static void ProtectConfiguration()
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.
                           OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Define the Rsa provider name.
    string provider = "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider";

    // Get the section to protect.
    ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.ConnectionStrings;

    if (connStrings != null)
    {
        if (!connStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            if (!connStrings.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
            {
                // Protect the section.
                connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);

                connStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

                Console.WriteLine("Section {0} is now protected by {1}",
                    connStrings.SectionInformation.Name,
                    connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectionProvider.Name);

            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(
                     "Can't protect, section {0} is locked",
                     connStrings.SectionInformation.Name);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Section {0} is already protected by {1}",
                connStrings.SectionInformation.Name,
                connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectionProvider.Name);

    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Can't get the section {0}",
            connStrings.SectionInformation.Name);

}
```

So, I wrote a quick program, and slapped the connection string to encrypt into its app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ODC" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=Password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username;Data Source=Server\Instance;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Database" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Running the program, the .exe.config now contained the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>r40SAb8XRp6w8KLAi+QOZiU9wBDBdQ5Z57QqibCdBTX1KlMXTGorCtjZS1jEzsRt+2qqTb1pRqkC81a8NSbEY0CtuR03nq8Wn8nFp+pEpNnT0fWEvxw9oCAF7HhxcrRao24AbMNzO+RnBIxDtBiCRieQdaQvR6Bp+//LheE8i6Z7MAeTPbKvD2RyFXBxEJ45MopNgGpq511GDaLen9tcaGPwRjO20Hwhoc2po1viqLd/UzEhpFFDrb7ffZm+p5ghUOjcysNHSnbUUJcNnv6z+IemTMytG6Ikr11cACs0NMfXeuA3Ab20btBoBILNq6I+l82p3gXKkNeCz+JV8UmCJA==</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So, I grabbed that and tried it in the ODC file I had, but Word just said 'Record 1 contained too few data fields', and when I clicked Ok it said 'Record 2 contained too few data fields', and then repeated a couple of times

Below is the ODC file in a working state, with the new section commented out.

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/x-ms-odc; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=ODC.Table>
<meta name=SourceType content=OLEDB>
<meta name=Catalog content="OurServer">
<meta name=Schema content=dbo>
<meta name=Table content="uvw_OurView">
<title>uvw_MMClientDetails</title>
<xml id=docprops><o:DocumentProperties
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <o:Description>Test</o:Description>
  <o:Name>uvw_OurView</o:Name>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
</xml><xml id=msodc><odc:OfficeDataConnection
  xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
   <odc:ConnectionString>Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=Password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username;Data Source=Server\Instance;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Database</odc:ConnectionString>

   <!--
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>r40SAb8XRp6w8KLAi+QOZiU9wBDBdQ5Z57QqibCdBTX1KlMXTGorCtjZS1jEzsRt+2qqTb1pRqkC81a8NSbEY0CtuR03nq8Wn8nFp+pEpNnT0fWEvxw9oCAF7HhxcrRao24AbMNzO+RnBIxDtBiCRieQdaQvR6Bp+//LheE8i6Z7MAeTPbKvD2RyFXBxEJ45MopNgGpq511GDaLen9tcaGPwRjO20Hwhoc2po1viqLd/UzEhpFFDrb7ffZm+p5ghUOjcysNHSnbUUJcNnv6z+IemTMytG6Ikr11cACs0NMfXeuA3Ab20btBoBILNq6I+l82p3gXKkNeCz+JV8UmCJA==</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
   -->

   <odc:CommandType>Table</odc:CommandType>
   <odc:CommandText>&quot;Database&quot;.&quot;dbo&quot;.&quot;uvw_OurView&quot;</odc:CommandText>
  </odc:Connection>
 </odc:OfficeDataConnection>
</xml>
<style>
<!--
    .ODCDataSource
    {
    behavior: url(dataconn.htc);
    }
-->
</style>

</head>

<body onload='init()' scroll=no leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 rightmargin=0 style='border: 0px'>
<table style='border: solid 1px threedface; height: 100%; width: 100%' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td id=tdName style='font-family:arial; font-size:medium; padding: 3px; background-color: threedface'>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
     <td id=tdTableDropdown style='padding: 3px; background-color: threedface; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 3px'>

      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id=tdDesc colspan='2' style='border-bottom: 1px threedshadow solid; font-family: Arial; font-size: 1pt; padding: 2px; background-color: threedface'>

      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='height: 100%; padding-bottom: 4px; border-top: 1px threedhighlight solid;'>
      <div id='pt' style='height: 100%' class='ODCDataSource'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script language='javascript'>

function init() {
  var sName, sDescription;
  var i, j;

  try {
    sName = unescape(location.href)

    i = sName.lastIndexOf(".")
    if (i>=0) { sName = sName.substring(1, i); }

    i = sName.lastIndexOf("/")
    if (i>=0) { sName = sName.substring(i+1, sName.length); }

    document.title = sName;
    document.getElementById("tdName").innerText = sName;

    sDescription = document.getElementById("docprops").innerHTML;

    i = sDescription.indexOf("escription>")
    if (i>=0) { j = sDescription.indexOf("escription>", i + 11); }

    if (i>=0 && j >= 0) {
      j = sDescription.lastIndexOf("</", j);

      if (j>=0) {
          sDescription = sDescription.substring(i+11, j);
        if (sDescription != "") {
            document.getElementById("tdDesc").style.fontSize="x-small";
          document.getElementById("tdDesc").innerHTML = sDescription;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  catch(e) {

    }
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried it with the connection string as it stands, called connectionStrings, and as the original was, called odc:ConnectionString, but neither worked.

Anyone know if I'm on the right track here, and just need to tweak something, or can ODC files / Word / Office 365 not handle encryption and configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" ?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database in question as an end-user? You may get prompts for password, etc., but CAN you? If yes, you can record the connection in a macro to see how Word builds the ConnectionString - it would resemble what's in the UDL, but will be in the form Word wants to have it. If you can get this to work, then this connection string can be assigned dynamically via the object model (whether VBA or an Add-in) in order to connect the document to the data source. Then you can concentrate on how to best obtain the variable information (password, for example)

Comment: re. the encrypted odc file thing, as far as I know, Office applications *maximally* follow the standard defined in [MS-ODCFF] (see, e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-odcff/ ), and I am pretty sure that only Excel interprets that format correctly. Word seems to use an older, unpublished version of the ODC standard and deviates from that in at least one respect.

Comment: Linking same question from MSDN forum, where I have moved the question from Azure SQL Database to Office 365 for Developers: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c4c4f60-7916-4c93-8c8c-e5d4d13636ac/word-office-365-mail-merge-alternative-to-udl-file-for-sql-azure-connection-string?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in two parts

**1) The Mail Merge**

The actual Mail Merge itself is performed by the main C# program using the Spire.PDF library. This removes the need for a UDL or ODC file for getting the data from the database into the documents.

**2) The Template File**

This still left the issue of creating the Mail Merge template file, with the merge fields from the views. This had to be doable from outside the main C# program, and previously required a UDL file.

I solve this issue by writing a Word Add-In, based on code from a blog on an Add-In company's site: https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/07/05/automating-word-mail-merge/

This Add-In adds a section to the 'Add-Ins' ribbon, named '[Our Product] Mail Merge', with a button 'Add Merge Fields'. Clicking the button opens a new form.

**Note**: This is an early version to test everything works, so not particularly pretty, missing some error checking etc.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RPMWordMailMergeAddIn
{
    public partial class MailMergeForm : Form
    {
        private static string connectionString = null;

        public MailMergeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (connectionString != null)
            {
                btnConnect_Click(null, null);
            }
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (connectionString == null || sender != null)
            {
                connectionString = <Call our 'Login to the Software' screen, 
                                    and return the restricted database user connection details>
                tvMailMergeTables.Nodes.Clear();
            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var views = connection.GetSchema("Views");

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(builder.InitialCatalog, 1, 1);
                rootNode.Tag = "Server";
                TreeNode viewsNode = rootNode.Nodes.Add("Views", "Views", 2, 2);

                foreach (DataRow view in views.Rows)
                {
                    var viewName = view.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                    if (viewName.StartsWith("uvw_MM") && !viewName.EndsWith("_X"))
                    {
                        TreeNode tableNode = viewsNode.Nodes.Add(viewName, viewName, 3, 3);
                        tableNode.Tag = "View";

                        var schemaOptions = new string[4];
                        schemaOptions[2] = viewName;

                        var columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns", schemaOptions);

                        foreach (DataRow column in columns.Rows)
                        {
                            var columnName = column.ItemArray[3].ToString();
                            TreeNode columnNode = tableNode.Nodes.Add(columnName, columnName, 6, 6);
                            columnNode.Tag = "Column";
                        }

                    }
                }

                tvMailMergeTables.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                rootNode.Expand();
                viewsNode.Expand();

                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void tvMailMergeTables_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode selectedNode = e.Node;
            if (selectedNode.Tag.ToString() == "Column" && selectedNode.IsSelected) // Fix for TreeView expanding bug
            {
                Word.Application wordApp = null;
                Word.Document doc = null;
                Word.Selection selection = null;
                Word.MailMerge wordMerge = null;
                Word.MailMergeFields wordMergeFields = null;

                try
                {
                    wordApp = ThisAddIn.application;
                    doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
                    wordMerge = doc.MailMerge;
                    wordMergeFields = wordMerge.Fields;
                    selection = wordApp.Selection;

                    wordMergeFields.Add(selection.Range, selectedNode.Text);

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (wordMergeFields != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordMergeFields);
                    }
                    if (wordMerge != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordMerge);
                    }
                    if (selection != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection);
                    }
                    if (doc != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This form then asks the User to log in to our software, and if they successfully do so it returns the connection string for a read-only database User, who only has access to the Mail Merge views.

A TreeView control is then populated with the views and their columns.

Double-clicking on a column name will add it to the Word document as a merge field at the current cursor position.

When saved, the Word document does not store any of the connection details.

So:-

- No UDL or ODC files required
- Valid software login required to see merge fields
- Merge field list always up to date as it's refreshed every time
- No connection details saved in the template or final mail merge documents

Just what I was after!

**Additional**

No longer required as part of this solution, but for completeness sake, it's also possible to do the Mail Merge from within the Add-In.

This requires an ODC file, but you can leave the Connection String section empty and pass it the Connection String instead, thus avoiding having details stored in plain text.

```
private void btnPerformMailMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word.Application wordApp = null;
    Word.Document doc = null;
    Word.MailMerge wordMerge = null;
    Word.MailMergeFields wordMergeFields = null;

    object sqlQuery = string.Empty;
    object connection = string.Empty;
    string odcPath = string.Empty;

    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Object oFalse = false;

    try
    {
        wordApp = ThisAddIn.application;
        doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
        wordMerge = doc.MailMerge;
        wordMergeFields = wordMerge.Fields;

        connection = connectionString;
        sqlQuery = String.Format("Select * From \"{0}\"", viewName);
        var name = @"Empty.odc";

        wordMerge.OpenDataSource(name, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref connection, ref sqlQuery, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        wordMerge.Destination = Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
        wordMerge.Execute(ref oFalse);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (wordMergeFields != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordMergeFields);
        }
        if (wordMerge != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordMerge);
        }
        if (doc != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as a comment but do not have the points for that.

Every approach to this that I know of suffers from a nasty problem: after Word has made a connection, whether via the UI or via OpenDataSource, the complete connection string, including (in the case of a connection to SQL Server) the username and password, is stored in the document.

In a .docx file it's stored in settings.xml in

```
<w:settings><w:mailMerge><w:odso><w:udl> .
```

I don't think you can avoid that, and of course it means that anyone who can save an unencrypted copy of the document can find the relevant connection info. I think you must already have seen that Word will not complete a connection unless you specify "saving the security information" when connecting.

In other words, anything you do that involves a direct connection to SQL Server has to deal with that problem somehow or other.

Incidentally, you always have to provide an external object of one kind or another in order to make a connection to SQL Server - either a machine or file ODBC DSN, a .udl file, or a .odc file. I do not think there is a way to encrypt any of them that Word can work with.

You used to be able to provide a completely empty .odc file and supply the connection info. in the ConnectString argument of the OpenDataSource call. If anything is going to allow you to solve the problem, it would be something along those lines, AFAIK it still suffers from the problem I describe above, but perhaps there is a solution.

If there really is no workaround to that, in my view you have two possible approaches:
 a. don't use mail merge. (e.g., write you own merge code)
 b. see if there is a way to get the data indirectly.

As for (b), you could perhaps create a Jet database that linked to your SQL Server data and use that as your data source. It isn't something I've explored in depth but it seems likely that Jet suffers from the same problem as Word, i.e. ends up storing security info. that can be inspected, or insists on using its own dialog to prompt for security info. which won't work for you either.

Alternatively if you are allowed to store data locally you could populate a Jet database from your SQL Server one and use that.

Jet is probably the most reliable intermediate format but if for example you need more than 255/256 columns you would have to use something else.

Another way to get the data indirectly would be to write your own OLEDB provider/ODBC Driver or Word file converter and make the connection from within that, and distribute that component.

Trouble is that none of those things is simple. For example, although Microsoft used to provide a "Simple OLEDB Provider" that let you create a provider by implementing a few simple interfaces, the resulting provider does not implement the OLE DB Command interface  which Word needs to be able to use. So you'd probably have to write a more complete OLE DB provider or ODBC Driver, or licence one of the 3rd party kits for doing that.

[[The converter approach is even more off-the-wall, but at this point I may as well outline it. It relies on misusing one of Word's text file conversion technologies. Not the newer one that uses .NET/COM (those converters can't be used for connecting to a data source), but a much older one via the link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/111716/how-to-obtain-the-winword-converter-sdk-gc1039)

The idea of that is that you write a converter that can open and recognise text files with a certain file extension (let's say ".sqs"), then converts chunks of the text in that file to RTF format and provides it to Word.

So to use it in this scenario you provide a suitable .sqs file (possibly with nothing in it, or possibly with some info that helps you connect to the correct data source). The file has to exist. But then instead of actually converting the text of that file, when Word asks for data, your code reads your database data and returns it in RTF format instead.]]

Comment: Linking same question from MSDN Azure SQL forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c4c4f60-7916-4c93-8c8c-e5d4d13636ac/word-office-365-mail-merge-alternative-to-udl-file-for-sql-azure-connection-string?forum=ssdsgetstarted